# abp backgroundjobmanager and load balancing

Tags: load-balancing, aspnetboilerplate, abp

we are using abp framework for our enterprise application.

i am wondering if it's neccessary to replace the default backgrundjob manager when using load balancing for the appservice in an azure environment?

would the hangfire integration of abp solve that issue?

Thank you and best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ABP Framework's default background job manager can only run in a single instance. If that's enough for you, then you can disable background job processing in all instances, except one of them. Or you can create a dedicated application (a simple console app, for example) to process the background jobs while others add jobs to the queue.

If you have too many background jobs and want to process them concurrently, you can easily replace with HangFire. Then refer to HangFire documentation to setup a clustered environment. So, yes it should solve the issue.